# How to query C# DataTable?

Tags: c#

I have created and returned datatable, this table has 10 columns. Now i want to filter from this table based on some dynamic search parameters. How to do this? any idea would be timely help.

```
// This function will create and return the source table.
var DisplayTable = CreateQueryTable();
```

Here I want to do dynamic search like `If col1=MyName and Col2=MyCity`

```
ResultGrid.DataSource = DisplayTable;
ResultGrid.DataBind();
Panel1.Controls.Add(ResultGrid);
```

Comment: Surely you'd want to filter in the SQL and only return the relevant results?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this in these way,

1.Creating DataView Like

```
var dv = dataTable.DefaultView;
dv.RowFilter =  "col1='MyName' and Col2='MyCity'"; // if MyName and MyCity are literal string.
```

or

```
dv.RowFilter = "col1='"+MyName+"' and Col2 ='"+ MyCity +"'";// if MyName and MyCity are string variable.
```

2.With DataTable Select Method, It will return array of DataRow

```
var rows = dataTable.Select("col1='MyName' and Col2='MyCity'"); //if string literal
```

or

```
var rows = dataTable.Select("col1='"+MyName+"' and Col2='"+MyCity+"'"); // if string variable
```

3.By Linq

```
var filterdData = from row in dataTable.AsEnumerable()
                  where row.Field<string>("col1") == "MyName" 
                  && row.Field<string>("col2") == "MyCity"
                  select row;
```

Answer (score 2):

you create DataView of your datatable and use Filter 
      // Create a DataView
      DataView dv = new DataView(yourDataTable);
      dv.RowFilter = "col1='MyName' and Col2='MyCity'";
      //Bind your grid with DataView

You can also use select method on your table

```
  DataRow[] foundRows;
  foundRows = yourDataTable.Select("col1='MyName' and Col2='MyCity'");
```

You can also use Linq To DataTable

```
var results = from myRow in yourDataTable.AsEnumerable()
where myRow.Field<string>("col1") == Myname &&
      myRow.Field<string>("Col2") == MyCity
select myRow;
```

Comment: can i use multiple search criteria here?

Comment: If data type for col1 and col2 are string, then your dv.RowFilter and Select method will not work.

Comment: @Candie, without the copy paste, ok, check your answer (Condition Sample : YourCol < 3 ).